# NDSolve of a 3-D function from interpolated data

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have a 3-D data set (linked in the comment below) obtained via numerical integration. I would like to generate an interpolating function, and then use this function to numerically solve an ODE. For reference, the 3-D function looks like this:

[image]

The data set is used to create the interpolated function:

`int = Interpolation[Flatten[Data1,1]]`

I then sought to use NDSolve for the ODE `xtraj'[T]==int[X,T]`, making the replacement `X->xtraj[T]`. I then sought to solve the ODE for `T=[-1,1]` for example. However I have not been successful in plotting the solution; using `ParametricPlot` does not yield anything.

```
ode = {xtraj'[T] == int[X, T] /. {X -> xtraj[T]}, xtraj[-2] == -2}
trajectories = NDSolve[ode, xtraj[T], {T, -1, 1}]
ParametricPlot[trajectories, {T, -1, 1}]
```

Any help as to why the solution is not plotting, or fixes re: syntax errors or a better solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: The link to the data is: 

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15g_0nog0tMuBg5_tGaQ?e=yxPmYs

Comment: The data seems to be a mixture of strings(?) and numeric! Can't use it!

Comment: My bad - try this!

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15g_0q-4IQKC1R8Oq4Eg?e=0j9Gda

@UlrichNeumann

Comment: Please provide usable data. Still there are parts like `42/25` which can't be evaluated!

Comment: Oh I see - this should work...

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak_7kWMZ0x15g_0q-4IQKC1R8Oq4Eg?e=dHxcUL

@UlrichNeumann

Comment: It's often possible to fold such a numerical integration into the differential equations, so that the solution becomes direct instead of your two-step NIntegrate-then-NDSolve. If you give the whole problem (including the integrals that produce your data), you'll likely get better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming rational expressions inside the data I first create usable data and interpolationfunction

```
data = Import["...data1.txt", "Table"] ;
xyz = Map[N[ToExpression[#]] &, data];

int = Interpolation[xyz]
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

The ode is

```
ode = {xtraj'[T] == int[xtraj[T], T], xtraj[-2] == -2}
```

Hope I understand `trajectories` right

```
trajectories = NDSolveValue[ode, xtraj, {T, -2, 2}]
Plot[Evaluate[trajectories[T]], {T, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I was incorrect in using ParametricPlot here... 

Thank you!